# Can PHP/Linux perform Microsoft Authenticode code signing?

Tags: linux, php, code-signing

My organization is currently in the process of obtaining a Microsoft Authenticode and we would like to see if we can integrate it into our current PHP-based deployment process.

Can PHP (or a shell command via shell_exec) perform Microsoft Authenticode code signing?

Comment: Don't know why this was doownvoted. It seems like a valid question. I don't have any experience here, but I don't see why this can't be made to work - but it might be fiddly.

Comment: I issued it.  The question is not clear.  The code signing certificate the author describes is good to sign executables.  It isn't clear what they want to use the certificate with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [Jsign](https://ebourg.github.io/jsign/) or [osslsigncode](https://github.com/mtrojnar/osslsigncode) from PHP to sign your files.